# How to populate the data with React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React.js and start learning myselve recently. Then I found this question from the internet but once I try few times to change the coding but still not able to resolve it. Could anyone tell me how to populate this data? Thanks

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      navigation: []
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.setState({
      navigation: [
        {
          key: 1,
          menu: 'SHOPEE_MALL',
          child: []
        },
        {
          key: 2,
          menu: 'SHOPEE_GAMES',
          child: [
            {
              key: 3,
              menu: 'SHOPEE_GOYANG',
              child: []
            },
            {
              key: 4,
              menu: 'SHOPEE_TANGKAP',
              child: []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    })
  }

  populate() {
    /* Your magic code here */

    console.log('zzzzz')
    return (
        this.state.navigation.map((navigation, key) => {
          return (
            <li key={key}>{navigation.menu}</li>
          )
        })
        
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.populate()}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.querySelector('React'))
```

**Code from https://jsitor.com/Odm75Xtu6**

Comment: Please find the code sandbox which has working version. You can update the logic to render recursively. https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-sky-tmg7h?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @PrakashS Looks same with the code in jsitor.com. But why the code there cant works?

Comment: The issue comes from the libraries, the code is fine. To resolve - click the `Add library` button, delete the existing react packages and add them again (by clicking `+React`). Cheers!